# Explain this behaviour with Python's str.format for "general" specifier, left-aligned sign-aware zero-padding. {0:<09.6g}

Tags: python, string-formatting

Can someone please explain how the 'general' format specifier works? I'm confused about how the left align with 0 padding works with this. I don't know if this is a bug in python or if I simply don't understand what the documentation is saying.

In the output below my confusion is in the last 3 blocks of printout, specifically the right most column. Could someone explain, with references to the documented format spec, why they're output like that, please?

(This is with `Python 3.4.0 (v3.4.0:04f714765c13, Mar 16 2014, 19:25:23) [MSC v.1600 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32`)

test.py:

```
t = [8123, 0.0, 1.0, 0.799999, 1.3243423487123]

for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:9g} {0:9.6g} {0:09.6g} ", v))
print()

for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:>9g} {0:>9.6g} {0:>09.6g} ", v))
print()

for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:=9g} {0:=9.6g} {0:=09.6g} ", v))
print()



# What is going on with the right column here???
for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:<9g} {0:<9.6g} {0:<09.6g} ", v))
print()

# What is going on with the right column here???
for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:<9,g} {0:<9,.6g} {0:<09,.6g} ", v))
print()


# Preceding the width field by a zero ('0') character enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types.
# This is equivalent to a fill character of '0' with an alignment type of '='.
#
# Why doesn't this right column do the same thing as above?
for v in t:
    print(str.format("{0:0=9g} {0:0=9.6g} {0:0=09.6g} ", v))
print()
```

The output of which is :

```
$ python3 test.py
     8123      8123 000008123 
        0         0 000000000 
        1         1 000000001 
 0.799999  0.799999 00.799999 
  1.32434   1.32434 001.32434 

     8123      8123 000008123 
        0         0 000000000 
        1         1 000000001 
 0.799999  0.799999 00.799999 
  1.32434   1.32434 001.32434 

     8123      8123 000008123 
        0         0 000000000 
        1         1 000000001 
 0.799999  0.799999 00.799999 
  1.32434   1.32434 001.32434 

8123      8123      812300000 
0         0         000000000 
1         1         100000000 
0.799999  0.799999  0.7999990 
1.32434   1.32434   1.3243400 

8,123     8,123     8,1230000 
0         0         000000000 
1         1         100000000 
0.799999  0.799999  0.7999990 
1.32434   1.32434   1.3243400 

000008123 000008123 000008123 
000000000 000000000 000000000 
000000001 000000001 000000001 
00.799999 00.799999 00.799999 
001.32434 001.32434 001.32434
```

Comment: You haven't actually stated what (specifically) you expected the output to be.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant documentation is the following:

> Preceding the width field by a zero (`'0'`) character enables sign-aware
>   zero-padding for numeric types. **This is equivalent to a `fill` character
>   of `'0'` with an alignment type of `'='`.**

Where the documentation for the `'='` align option is:

> Forces the padding to be placed after the sign (if any) but before the
>   digits. This is used for printing fields in the form `+000000120`.
>   This alignment option is only valid for numeric types.

While `<` and `>` respectively left and right align the given item:

> **Forces** the field to be left-aligned within the available space (this
>   is the default for most objects).
>
> **Forces** the field to be right-aligned within the available space (this
>   is the default for numbers).

Note the use of the verb *forces*. I believe here it's stating that if `<` is specified then the output is left-aligned. Period. Other implied alignments aren't considered (e.g. the `=` implied by `0` filling).

This explains all the examples you provided: if you put a `<` then the output is left-aligned even using `09.6g` which should do zero padding. Did you expect that the `<` would simply be ignored? I believe this would be a bad choice because since `<` is *explicit* it ought to be honored, while the *implicit* `=` should be overriden.

I don't get what puzzles you in the last example because the output **is** perfectly equivalent to the first output, which is consistent with the above documentation.